# How to change SharePoint list or library.: Shortcut keys(Edited)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Has anyone tried to change shortcut keys of a SharePoint button?

I want to change the save button access key which is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, for list form.

Note:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Tools : Options
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Opens a dialog box where you can browse for a file to upload